# How to connect to Windows remote domain from Linux know its gateway hostname?

Tags: linux, networking, ssh, remote-desktop, hostname

I have credentials to connect to my University's reserved Linux virtual machine which means :

- username
- password
- gateway's hostname let's say `secretgateway.net`
- full hostname in `.local` domain let's say it's `myscrethostname.local`
- domain I need to connect to let's say `pluto`

and some other stuff. How can I connect to this machine (either via RDP or preferably SSH ) from Ubuntu being in a remote network ?

**EDIT** I have the needed `.rdp` which I can open in Windows and connect to the machine but when I use Ubuntu's remote desktop connection (Remmina) it tries to connect straight to the hostname.local which I presume won't work.

Comment: What's the FQDN for the machine? Obviously it's not just hostname.local. I assume Windows accounts for the network you're already connecting from to likely complete that.

Comment: I have updated the answer. I know that I have to connect to a windows domain and I can do that with `domainjoin-cli` from `likewise-open5` package but how do I do that since I only know domain name `pluto` ?

Answer (score 0):

For now I have been able to connect with Remmina on a remote computer not in my LAN doing these steps on two different levels:

a) **the remote computer at work** (eg Windows):

1. must be powered on (not in standby or hibernate mode)
2. with enabled remote desktop option for your user authentication
3. with firewall enabled for *remote assistance* and *remote desktop* on
   `local` and `public` IP
4. you need to know its public IP, that can change for which you may
   choose to create/know a relative Dynamic DNS (DDNS). To know your
   public IP on remote computer, you can launch the following command
   on the remote computer, that works either on Windows or on Linux:

   `nslookup myip.opendns.com resolver1.opendns.com`

   on a remote Linux you can also run a script like the following:

   `#!/bin/bash
   myip="$(dig +short myip.opendns.com @resolver1.opendns.com)"
   echo "${myip}" > ~/Desktop/my_public_ip.txt`
5. if your remote public IP changes, you need to repeat the step 4 to
   know your new public IP (not necessary if you use a Dynamic DNS) and
   use it to configure your router at home
6. I don't know if necessary, but maybe can be necessary open 3389
   port also in the remote router: omit this sixth step for now and
   proceed further

b) **your computer at home** (eg. Linux):

1. you need to configure your router, enabling the port 3389 associated
   with your local IP, by using the protocol TCP
2. you need to open the port 3389 in the firewall; in Linux, for
   example, you can run the command:
   `$ sudo firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-port=3389/tcp --permanent`
3. Install Remmina; in Fedora, for example: `$ sudo dnf install remmina*`
4. open remmina and setup the remote desktop by using a `RDP` protocol,
   indicating the remote public IP with the port (`x.x.x.x:3389`) as
   server, your `username` and `password`, a domain (like `WORKGROUP`) if
   any, set `client resolution`, depth color to `Truecolor 32 bpp`, a
   folder to share if any, and, in *advanced tab*, `good` as quality, `NLA`
   (Network Level Authentication: for me it worked) or `RDP` as security.
   Save and connect, accepting the certificate request

**Other tools**

To solve the unwanted behavior found by using Remmina (and similar), that redirects the remote user to Windows lock screen, allowing only one user to be logged, you need to avoid RDP protocol.

Here a list of alternative tools:

a) NoMachine or NX that use X11 forwarding through SSH protocol

b) Anydesk

c) UltraVNC

a) NoMachine or NX that use X11 forwarding through SSH

b) Anydesk

c) UltraVNC